# Does require cascade in php?

Tags: php, joomla

I've got three files, `a.php`, `b.php` and `c.php`.

a.php:`require b.php`

b.php: `require c.php`

Can I use features from `c.php` in `a.php`?  It's not working for me, but I think I'm doing something wrong.  W3 Schools, tiztag, etc aren't helpful.

Real code:
`default.php`:
`require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controllers'.DS.'easyblog.php');`

`/controllers/easyblog.php`:
`include JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'helpers'.DS.'easyblog.php'`

`/helpers/easyblog.php`
`function getDefault()`

I get the following error when I try to run this:
    Fatal error: Call to undefined method xmlrpcHelper::getDefault() in /helpers/easyblog.php on line 43

(addendum: Could using require_once or includes mess this up?)

Comment: Yes, and it is easily testable.

Comment: Do you get any errors? In PHP this is acceptable

Comment: W3schools is *never* helpful. What exactly do you mean by "features" though - constants? Variables? Functions?

Comment: @Filype:Yes.  I'm working with some inherited code that does it and I get an "undefined method" error.

Comment: Could you please post what code you're working with? You should be able to call anything from a file you've required, after you required it.

Comment: 9 out of 10 times including or requiring something in PHP is the same as copying and pasting that file in place of the require/include call.

Comment: You will need to require the files in the right order for example to use functions from c.php in a.php you will need to put 'C' before 'A'

Comment: You must include the file B.php (which includes your C.php) before calling any functionality out of C.php.

Comment: @clentfort that was it.  Thanks!  For some reason the include was halfway down the file.  I thought that was normal....  (new to PHP).  Make it an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

"It's not working for me" is not an error message - perhaps if you explained in more details what you were doing and why you thought it had failed you might get a more specific response as to why.